# how to output all object proposals in py-faster rcnn

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I tried to run py-faster-rcnn `./tools/demo.py` and got the following results.

```
Loaded network /root/py-faster-rcnn/data/faster_rcnn_models/VGG16_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Demo for data/demo/000003.jpg
Detection took 0.117s for 89 object proposals
```

But it only displayed one object proposal when I save the image result. How could I save the results of all 89 object proposals?